# Extract records from PostgreSQL based on time of day component of timestamp/DateTime in Rails Active Record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I am working with a PostgreSQL database in a rails application and facing a challenge in extracting the user records on the basis of only the time component from `timestamp` type `created_at` column in my users table.

This query works fine:

```ruby
users = User.where("    DATE_PART('hour',   created_at) >= ? 
                    AND DATE_PART('minute', created_at) >= ? 
                    OR  DATE_PART('hour',   created_at) <= ? 
                    AND DATE_PART('minute', created_at) <= ?", 
                    10, 0, 15, 30).pluck :created_at
```

But I'm curious if there's a more elegant approach to extract the desired records. Essentially, I aim to query records based solely on time, excluding the date. For instance, I want to retrieve all users created between `10:00` and `12:30` on any day (year, month and day do not matter).

I also tried this:

```
User.where("EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) BETWEEN ? AND ?", 14, 15)
```

but it's only dealing with hours not with the minutes.

Desired time could be `10`-`12` hours or `10:00`-`12:30`.
How can I manage these minutes if I want to extract the records from `10:00` to `12:30`?

In short, I'm seeking method where I can specify the desired time and obtain all records within those time slots.

Comment: PostgreSQL has a `time` type, that you can cast `timestamp` to in order to extract everything from hours down, in one go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL has a [`time`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) type, that you can cast `timestamp` to in order to extract everything from hours down (not excluding seconds and fractions of seconds), in one go. [Demo at db<>fiddle:](https://dbfiddle.uk/wvxE5h_J)

```
create table test(created_at timestamp);

--sample timestamps around every hour between now and 4 days from now
insert into test select g+random()*'1h'::interval 
from generate_series(now(),now()+'4 days','1h')_(g);
```

```sql
select created_at
from test
where created_at::time between '11:15' and '12:21:10.123';
```

| created_at |
| --- |
| 2023-12-08 11:55:58.167576 |
| 2023-12-09 11:39:04.189425 |
| 2023-12-10 12:09:11.234004 |
| 2023-12-11 11:40:42.80833 |

From RoR, you can pass the time fields into PostgreSQL [`make_time()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#id-1.5.8.15.6.2.2.31.1.1.1). The third field is a `double precision`, which allows you to pass seconds with fractions:

```ruby
User.where("created_at::time BETWEEN make_time(?,?,?) 
                             AND     make_time(?,?,?)", 
           11, 15, 0, 
           12, 21, 10.123)
```

You can also pass any timestamp with a matching time, and cast to only use its `time` element:

```ruby
User.where("created_at::time BETWEEN cast(:start_time as time) 
                             AND     cast(:end_time   as time)", 
           {start_time: Time.new(2023,12,07,11,15), 
            end_time: DateTime.new(1981,05,05,15,30)} )
```

It's possible to further speed this up by adding a [functional index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) on `created_at`:

```sql
create index on test((created_at::time));
```

Comment: How can I achieve the Rails model-level query for this? The same query is taking too long, and I'm looking for a more efficient(a short) way to do this

Comment: If anything, it's faster: here's [a test on 260k samples](https://dbfiddle.uk/sG0AlCsG). It also doesn't sacrifice everything below full minutes, or require you to write out a `date_part()`/`extract()` for every field.

Comment: @gulRanaa I've added examples how you can use this from RoR, updated the demo and added a remark about index that can speed this up further.